# Finding IP Camera using OpenCV

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

So this is what I have currently following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gH_kQZo-NSk).

```
#number 0 is front web cam, number 1 is back webcam 
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture.set(3, 640)
capture.set(4, 480)

while True: 
    success, img = capture.read()
    cv2.imshow("video", img)

    #This function loops -> Delay -> press Q it breaks loop 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord('q'):
        break`
```

This works great if I wanted to use my webcams. I do not.

I have an Ethernet camera attached to an Ethernet injector which runs to my PC using an Ethernet to USB adapter attached to a USB hub.

**Hardware**

1. Ethernet Camera -> 2. Ethernet Injector -> 3. Ethernet USB Adapter -> 4. USB Hub

OS: Windows 10

1. [Mako G503C](https://www.alliedvision.com/en/products/cameras/detail/Mako%20G/G-503.html)
2. [Tp-Link TL-POE150S](https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/accessory/tl-poe150s/)
3. [Insignia USB to Ethernet](https://www.insigniaproducts.com/pdp/NS-PU98505/6233049)
4. [BYEASY USB Hub, 4 Port USB 3.0 Hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FH7XJCD)

**Question:** How would I find the Ethernet camera and implement it into my code?

Thanks,

J

Comment: You might mention the make/model of your camera, of the injector and your operating system/version.

Comment: You mean ip camera?

Comment: Correct. I fixed it.

Comment: How do u open ur camera on ur browser

Comment: I don't open it on my browser. I use 'VIMBA Viewer' right now to see through the camera.

Comment: Do you see your camera listed under Cameras in device manager? (use crtl+x to open it)

Comment: Under 'Cameras' only my webcam comes up. Under 'Universal Serial Bus Controllers' I see Generic SuperSPEED USB Hub, Generic USB Hub, Intel USB 3.0 Extensible Host Controller, USB Composite Device, and USB Root Hub

Comment: You need a rtsp link to use it with opencv

Comment: So I used the cameras IP 'rtsp://169.xxx.xxx.xx' and nothing,

Answer (score 0):

This issue is old, but just in case someone has the same issue. Use the VimbaPython example for asynchronous streaming with openCV from GitHub.

[GitHub VimbaPython examples](https://github.com/alliedvision/VimbaPython/tree/master/Examples)

You use Vimba to open the camera and access the frames and convert them to an openCV format. Then you can continue image manipulation/analysis with openCV. With the Mako specifically, some pixel formats won't be compatible with VimbaPython, but the non-packed ones should be fine.